# iPhone Memory Leakage When Initializing NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, analyzer

I am getting a memory leak for each object that is added to glossTerms (apart from the first object). The leak is described as having "A +1 retain count (owning reference)" - I have searched the Internet and have found a couple of threads which mention using "copy" inside the object allocation. I tried this but I must not have implemented it properly as I was still having memory leaks.

```
- (void)createTermData {

NSMutableArray *glossTerms=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[glossTerms addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                       initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Approximate",@"term",
                       @"Test",@"definition",@"Test2",@"example",nil]];

[glossTerms addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                       initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Arithmetic Mean",@"term",
                       @"Test",@"definition",@"Test2",@"example",nil]];

termData=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
            glossTerms,nil];

[glossTerms release];
```

If any of you are able to shed any light on this, I'd be very grateful.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An NSArray will retain any object you add to it and release it automatically, either at the end of it's lifecycle or once you remove it from the array (if it's mutable).

When you allocate an object, it's retain count is +1.

Therefore, when you allocate an object and add it to an array, it's retain count is +2. This means that you must either autorelease the object (which is what I'd do in your case, since you're allocating on the same line you're adding) or release it after adding it if you have a reference to the pointer. In your case, you don't have a reference, so autoreleasing it is your best bet.

```
NSMutableArray *glossTerms=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[glossTerms addObject:[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                       initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Approximate",@"term",
                       @"Test",@"definition",@"Test2",@"example",nil] autorelease]];

[glossTerms addObject:[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                       initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Arithmetic Mean",@"term",
                       @"Test",@"definition",@"Test2",@"example",nil] autorelease]];

termData=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
            glossTerms,nil];

[glossTerms release];
```

FWIW, the static methods [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWith...] return an autoreleased object automatically.

Comment: Mike this was a great response, thank you very much for this answer.  Perfectly solved my problem!